# Is this proof of continuity correct?

Tags: real-analysis

The question from my textbook states: "Let $|f|$ be the function whose value at each $x$ in the domain of $f$ is $|f(x)|$. Prove that if $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, then so is $|f|$. Is the converse true?"

First, I chose $\epsilon > 0$. I then argued that by the triangle inequality, $$||f(x)| - |f(x_0)|| \leq |f(x) - f(x_0)|$$ so $$|x-x_0| < \delta$$ implies that $$||f(x)| - |f(x_0)|| \leq |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$$ so $|f(x)|$ must be continuous.

I'm not entirely sure how to show that the converse isn't necessarily true. My intuition is that since $||f(x)| - |f(x_0)|| \leq |f(x) - f(x_0)|$, the expression to the right of the inequality doesn't necessarily have to be less than $\epsilon$.

I'm not sure if my answers are reasoned properly, so I'd love to hear feedback.

Comment: Are we in a Banach space? The reals? A vector space? A metric space?

Comment: This is from a real analysis textbook, so I assume that this should be for the reals.

Comment: Hint: Can you find two different real numbers $a,b$ such that $|a|=|b|$? If so, consider the function $f$ defined by $f(0)=a$ and $f(x)=b$ for all $x\neq0$. Observe that $|f|$ is a constant function. Is $f$ continuous?

Comment: "so |f(x)| must be continuous".  You told as a given that $|f(x)|$ was continuous.  You have to prove or disprove that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: My first question from this post is if I successfully proved that $|f|$ is continuous. If I did, I'd love to know.

Comment: Your proof is correct, if not very carefully or elegantly stated. In particular, you aren't clear about where $\delta$ comes from. You should say something along the lines of: "by assumption of the continuity of $f$, we know there exists $\delta$ such that ... ."

Comment: Noted, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to provide a counterexample to prove a universal statement.

Here, we resort to a modified [Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_continuous_function#Dirichlet_function):

$$f: x \mapsto \begin{cases}
1 & x \in \Bbb Q \\
-1 & x \in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q
\end{cases}$$

(Note its difference from the original Dirichlet function.)

Then, $|f|$ is constant everywhere (hence continuous) but $f$ is continuous nowhere.

Comment: To *disprove* a statement?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, which is very helpful. Would you mind commenting on whether my proof that if $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, then so is $|f|$ is correct?

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing we know about $f$ is that $|f|$ is continuous, we have no idea when $f$ is positive or negative.  For all we know $f$ can hop about like a flea between positive and negative values.

Let $|f(x)| = 5|x|$.  But $f(x) = 5x$ if $x \in \mathbb Q$ and $f(x) = -5x$ if $x \not \in \mathbb Q$.  $|f(x)|$ is continuous and $f(x)$ is not.